# ORA-65096: Problema con la creacion de un usuario en oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Estoy en sql plus de `oracle 18c` queriendo crear un usuario para un `tablespace`:

```
create unidad3 identified by admin default
  2  tablespace Bitacora temporary tablespace temp;
```

Ya he intentado cambiar el código y ponerlo de diferentes maneras pero aún así no me sale, me marca este error:

> ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol com·n no vßlido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no estas especificando lo que quieres hacer `create unidad3 identified by admin default` usuario tablespace,triger?

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
// or
sqlplus sys as sysdba
// or
sqlplus system as sysdba
//or
sqlplus /nolog
conn sys as sysdba


create user unidad3 identified by admin;
// por default el tablespace es user y el temporary es temp
alter user unidad3 default tablespace Bitacora;
```

NOTA: el password `admin` no cumple los requisitos minimos de complijidad para un passsword!

validar que se este trabajando con contenedores `12C` en adelante:

```
SQL> select name FROM V$PDBS;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDB$SEED
DBPROD_PDB1

SQL> alter session set container=DBPROD_PDB1;

Session altered.

SQL> create user UNIDAD3 identified by "admin";

User created.

SQL>
```

**nota:** PDB$SEED es la plantilla por defecto para la creacion de otros pdbs

Comment: Quiero agregarle un usuario a un tablespace, ya lo escribi como me lo dijiste y sigue el mismo error. (también puse una contraseña más complicada)

Comment: debes estar trabajando con contenedores... te agrege un ejemplo en el caso de que sea asi!

Comment: Escribí tu ejemplo y me arroja lo mismo

Comment: SQL> alter session set container=DBPROD_PDB1;
ERROR:
ORA-65011: La base de datos de conexi¾n DBPROD_PDB1 no existe.


SQL> create user UNIDAD3 identified by "admin";
create user UNIDAD3 identified by "admin"
            *
ERROR en lÝnea 1:
ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol com·n no vßlido

Comment: esto...................! si notaste que el  `DBPROD_PDB1` es el nombre de mi pdb???? este nombre puede varias ya que lo asigna el usuario a la hora de la creacion! con el comando anterior te muestra los `pdbs` disponibles.... nota: `PDB$SEED` es el de root no tocar!

Comment: Muchas gracias si funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que quieres que tenga rol de administrador. Intenta lo siguiente:

1. conectar primero en el usuario system con rol administrador con: `connect system as sysdba;` e introducir la contraseña puesta en la instalación.
2. Crear el usuario con `create user unidad3 identified by admin;`. El usuario sería "unidad3" y la contraseña "admin" si quieres puedes cambiarlos por los que quieras.
3. Dar permisos de administrador al usuario: `grant sysdba to unidad3`. Si pones otro usuario aquí tienes que poner también el nombre que hayas puesto en ved de "unidad3".

Comment: Hola, ya escribí la primera linea que me dijiste la de: connect system as sysdba y pongo mi contraseña y me dice que estoy conectada, pero nuevamente al crear el usuario me devuelve el mismo error.